# Convert String to KeyEvents

Tags: java, awtrobot

I want to convert a String into KeyEvent to do something like this :

```
writeKeyboard(myBot,"abcd");

public void writeKeyboard(Robot bot, String st){
     char[] arr = arr.toCharArray();
     int i = arr.length();
     int j = 0;
     int keycode;
     while (j<i) {
         keycode = arr[j].something;
         bot.keyPress(keycode);
         bot.keyRelease(keycode);
         j++;
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a simple answer for this.  A similar question has been asked before here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664896/get-the-vk-int-from-an-arbitrary-char-in-java

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I'm basically using a glorified `switch` statement. Simple and fast:

```
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;

public class Keyboard {

    private Robot robot;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
        keyboard.type("Hello there, how are you?");
    }

    public Keyboard() throws AWTException {
        this.robot = new Robot();
    }

    public Keyboard(Robot robot) {
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    public void type(CharSequence characters) {
        int length = characters.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char character = characters.charAt(i);
            type(character);
        }
    }

    public void type(char character) {
        switch (character) {
        case 'a': doType(VK_A); break;
        case 'b': doType(VK_B); break;
        case 'c': doType(VK_C); break;
        case 'd': doType(VK_D); break;
        case 'e': doType(VK_E); break;
        case 'f': doType(VK_F); break;
        case 'g': doType(VK_G); break;
        case 'h': doType(VK_H); break;
        case 'i': doType(VK_I); break;
        case 'j': doType(VK_J); break;
        case 'k': doType(VK_K); break;
        case 'l': doType(VK_L); break;
        case 'm': doType(VK_M); break;
        case 'n': doType(VK_N); break;
        case 'o': doType(VK_O); break;
        case 'p': doType(VK_P); break;
        case 'q': doType(VK_Q); break;
        case 'r': doType(VK_R); break;
        case 's': doType(VK_S); break;
        case 't': doType(VK_T); break;
        case 'u': doType(VK_U); break;
        case 'v': doType(VK_V); break;
        case 'w': doType(VK_W); break;
        case 'x': doType(VK_X); break;
        case 'y': doType(VK_Y); break;
        case 'z': doType(VK_Z); break;
        case 'A': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_A); break;
        case 'B': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_B); break;
        case 'C': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_C); break;
        case 'D': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_D); break;
        case 'E': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_E); break;
        case 'F': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_F); break;
        case 'G': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_G); break;
        case 'H': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_H); break;
        case 'I': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_I); break;
        case 'J': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_J); break;
        case 'K': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_K); break;
        case 'L': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_L); break;
        case 'M': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_M); break;
        case 'N': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_N); break;
        case 'O': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_O); break;
        case 'P': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_P); break;
        case 'Q': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Q); break;
        case 'R': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_R); break;
        case 'S': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_S); break;
        case 'T': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_T); break;
        case 'U': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_U); break;
        case 'V': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_V); break;
        case 'W': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_W); break;
        case 'X': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_X); break;
        case 'Y': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Y); break;
        case 'Z': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Z); break;
        case '`': doType(VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '0': doType(VK_0); break;
        case '1': doType(VK_1); break;
        case '2': doType(VK_2); break;
        case '3': doType(VK_3); break;
        case '4': doType(VK_4); break;
        case '5': doType(VK_5); break;
        case '6': doType(VK_6); break;
        case '7': doType(VK_7); break;
        case '8': doType(VK_8); break;
        case '9': doType(VK_9); break;
        case '-': doType(VK_MINUS); break;
        case '=': doType(VK_EQUALS); break;
        case '~': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '!': doType(VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK); break;
        case '@': doType(VK_AT); break;
        case '#': doType(VK_NUMBER_SIGN); break;
        case '$': doType(VK_DOLLAR); break;
        case '%': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_5); break;
        case '^': doType(VK_CIRCUMFLEX); break;
        case '&': doType(VK_AMPERSAND); break;
        case '*': doType(VK_ASTERISK); break;
        case '(': doType(VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case ')': doType(VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case '_': doType(VK_UNDERSCORE); break;
        case '+': doType(VK_PLUS); break;
        case '\t': doType(VK_TAB); break;
        case '\n': doType(VK_ENTER); break;
        case '[': doType(VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case ']': doType(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '\\': doType(VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case '{': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case '}': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '|': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case ';': doType(VK_SEMICOLON); break;
        case ':': doType(VK_COLON); break;
        case '\'': doType(VK_QUOTE); break;
        case '"': doType(VK_QUOTEDBL); break;
        case ',': doType(VK_COMMA); break;
        case '<': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_COMMA); break;
        case '.': doType(VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '>': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '/': doType(VK_SLASH); break;
        case '?': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_SLASH); break;
        case ' ': doType(VK_SPACE); break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
        }
    }

    private void doType(int... keyCodes) {
        doType(keyCodes, 0, keyCodes.length);
    }

    private void doType(int[] keyCodes, int offset, int length) {
        if (length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        robot.keyPress(keyCodes[offset]);
        doType(keyCodes, offset + 1, length - 1);
        robot.keyRelease(keyCodes[offset]);
    }

}
```

If you want some custom key typing, you can extend the class and override the `type(char)` method. For example:

```
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;

public class WindowUnicodeKeyboard extends Keyboard {

    private Robot robot;

    public WindowUnicodeKeyboard(Robot robot) {
        super(robot);
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    @Override
    public void type(char character) {
        try {
            super.type(character);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            String unicodeDigits = String.valueOf(Character.getCodePoint(character));
            robot.keyPress(VK_ALT);
            for (int i = 0; i < unicodeDigits.length(); i++) {
                typeNumPad(Integer.parseInt(unicodeDigits.substring(i, i + 1)));
            }
            robot.keyRelease(VK_ALT);
        }
    }

    private void typeNumPad(int digit) {
        switch (digit) {
        case 0: doType(VK_NUMPAD0); break;
        case 1: doType(VK_NUMPAD1); break;
        case 2: doType(VK_NUMPAD2); break;
        case 3: doType(VK_NUMPAD3); break;
        case 4: doType(VK_NUMPAD4); break;
        case 5: doType(VK_NUMPAD5); break;
        case 6: doType(VK_NUMPAD6); break;
        case 7: doType(VK_NUMPAD7); break;
        case 8: doType(VK_NUMPAD8); break;
        case 9: doType(VK_NUMPAD9); break;
        }
    }

}
```

There is, of course, room for improvement, but you get the idea.

Comment: Great example, remember when using this to have a static import for the key codes:

`import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;`

Comment: @klogd I've added the static import to the example code, since I missed it too.

Comment: Does this produce the same result on azerty and qwerty keyboard?

Comment: On my Windows 7 x64 with JDK 1.7.0_25, I had to modify the line for colon to case ':': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_SEMICOLON); break; Otherwise, an excellent solution!

Comment: For a LinuxUnicodeKeyboard support, the key combination is CTRL + SHIFT + u, then you type the unicode code and finish by pressing  ENTER.
It looks working for Linux Mint & Ubuntu.

Comment: Great code, thanks! But this doesn't work for all the keys requiring 2 pressed button combinations like !, @, $, % etc since they originally are Shift + 1, Shift + 2 etc

Comment: Doesn't work for underscore . I get an invalid keycode.  I tended to use Character ranges instead. (You can use Character.isLowecase() ... isUppercase() ... isDigit() to simplify most of them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38784903/495157 - they had issue in C# .. We don't have OEM minus here in Java though. Use VK_SHIFT and VK_MINUS

Answer (score 26):

I used the clipboard to solve the problem...

```
public static void type(String characters) {
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection( characters );
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, clipboardOwner);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
}
```

Comment: instance is a class implementing the ClipBoardOwner interface see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html#setContents(java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable, java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner), I edited my answer to be more verbose

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO because it does NOT include another java file.

Comment: `clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, clipboardOwner);` should probably be `clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);`

Comment: clipboardOwner is an instance of a class implementing the ClipBoardOwner interface see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html#setContents(java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable

Comment: You might as well pass null for second value of setContents - unless you want to do something like this: https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0382.html

Answer (score 10):

You can do it simply via Java reflection API:

```
public void writeKeyboard(Robot bot, String st) {
    String upperCase = st.toUpperCase();

    for(int i = 0; i < upperCase.length(); i++) {
        String letter = Character.toString(upperCase.charAt(i));
        String code = "VK_" + letter

        Field f = KeyEvent.class.getField(code);
        int keyEvent = f.getInt(null);

        bot.press(keyEvent);
        bot.release(keyEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is appropriate, but only for those characters which don't require `Shift` to be pressed while desired key input.

Comment: Also things like underscore!

Answer (score 6):

I recently wrote a class to do this. It enters the Alt code of each character, instead of figuring out the key combination for every case individually. Not the fastest solution, but it's concise and works for a very wide range of characters.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ALT;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0;

public class Altbot extends Robot{

    Altbot()throws AWTException{}

    public void type(CharSequence cs){
        for(int i=0;i<cs.length();i++){
            type(cs.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    public void type(char c){
        keyPress(VK_ALT);
        keyPress(VK_NUMPAD0);
        keyRelease(VK_NUMPAD0);
        String altCode=Integer.toString(c);
        for(int i=0;i<altCode.length();i++){
            c=(char)(altCode.charAt(i)+'0');
            //delay(20);//may be needed for certain applications
            keyPress(c);
            //delay(20);//uncomment if necessary
            keyRelease(c);
        }
        keyRelease(VK_ALT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, the delay is not needed. Robot will automatically put delays in between actions if needed.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I managed to use all available keys. Create a Map and fill the map using the method fillKeyMap. Now you can use String representation of key events and convert it back into KeyEvent codes using the map.

```
/** Create map with string values to integer pairs
 */
public static final void fillKeyMap(Map<String, Integer> into) {
    try {
        Field[] fields = KeyEvent.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f : fields) {
            if(f.getName().startsWith("VK_")) { //we only want these fields
                int code = ((Integer)f.get(null)).intValue();
                into.put(f.getName().substring(3), code);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a Kludge, but you can use the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_patternKeyEvent.) to encapsulate the keystrokes for each character in the String, then get the Command for each character in turn and invoke the method. The advantage of this is that you only have to set up the map once. The disadvantage is it still involves a bunch of bolierplate:

```
public interface Command {
    void pressKey(Robot bot);
}

//add a command to the map for each keystroke
commandMap.put("A", new Command() {
    void pressKey(Robot bot) {
        pressWithShift(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    }
});
commandMap.put ("a", new Command() {
    void pressKey (Robot bot) {
        press (KeyEvent.VK_A);
    }
});
commandMap.put("B", new Command() {
    void pressKey(Robot bot) {
        pressWithShift(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    }
});
...
//loads more definitions here

//helper methods
private void pressWithShift (Robot bot, KeyEvent event) {
    bot.keyPress (KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    press(bot, event);
    bot.keyRelase(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
}

private void press(Robot bot, KeyEvent event) {
    bot.keyPress(event);
    bot.keyRelease(event);
}
```

Then to use the Map:

```
for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
    String subString = st.substring(i, i + 1);

    commandMap.get(subString).pressKey(bot);
}
```

Comment: +1 this is the right approach but I think it needs too much boilderplate code

Comment: @dfa I do too, really this should all be done by some RobotHelper in my opinion. What would you do to reduce the boilerplate?

Answer (score 3):

I'm basically using the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) as Rich Seller does in his answer, with two minor modifications for the brevity's sake:

- use of the [Decoration pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for reusing instances of a-z command
- use of reflection to remove KeyEvent.VK_???

Command interface:

```
interface Command {

    void pressKey(Robot robot);
}
```

and the decorator (for modification #1):

```
class ShiftCommand implements Command {

    private final Command command;

    public ShiftCommand(Command command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void pressKey(Robot robot) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        command.pressKey(robot);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SHIFT + " + command.toString();
    }
}
```

using this helper (for modification #2):

```
public static int getKeyEvent(Character c) {
    Field f = KeyEvent.class.getField("VK_" + Character.toUpperCase(c));
    f.setAccessible(true);
    return (Integer) f.get(null);
}
```

**BEWARE**: I'm not handling exceptions here, this is left as exercise for you :))

then populating the command using a for loop:

```
Map<Character, Command> commandMap = new HashMap<Character, Command>();

    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
        final Character c = Character.valueOf((char) i);
        Command pressKeyCommand = new Command() {

            public void pressKey(Robot robot) {
                int keyEventCode = getKeyEvent(c);
                robot.keyPress(c);
                robot.keyRelease(c);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return String.format("%c", c);
            }
        };

        // 'a' .. 'z'
        commandMap.put(c, pressKeyCommand);
        // 'A' .. 'Z' by decorating pressKeyCommand
        commandMap.put(Character.toUpperCase(c), new ShiftCommand(pressKeyCommand));
    }
```

### TestCase

```
String test = "aaaBBB";
for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
     System.out.println(commandMap.get(test.charAt(i)));
}
```

as expected this outputs:

```
a
a
a
SHIFT + b
SHIFT + b
SHIFT + b
```

Comment: how does this handle non-alpha characters?

Comment: wasn't trying to be critical - I like the approach, but it's probably worth pointing out that you need to handle non-alpha keys in a similar manner to my answer

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer seems very bloated to me.  Here is a little more concise solution that is sort of based off of the accepted answer.  It should handle pretty much any use case.  Also handles `\n` (newline), `\t` (tab), and `\b` (backspace), as demonstrated in the example.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.AWTKeyStroke;
import static java.awt.AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke;
import java.awt.Robot;
import static java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Keyboard {

    private final Robot robot;

    public Keyboard() throws AWTException {
        this.robot = new Robot();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
        Thread.sleep(3000L);
        Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
        keyboard.type("`1234567890-=[]\\;',./\n");
        keyboard.type("~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?\n");
        keyboard.type("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n\tABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        keyboard.type("\n\n\twh\bat");
    }

    private static AWTKeyStroke getKeyStroke(char c) {
        String upper = "`~'\"!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?";
        String lower = "`~'\"1234567890-=[]\\;,./";

        int index = upper.indexOf(c);
        if (index != -1) {
            int keyCode;
            boolean shift = false;
            switch (c) {
                // these chars need to be handled specially because
                // they don't directly translate into the correct keycode
                case '~':
                    shift = true;
                case '`':
                    keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE;
                    break;
                case '\"':
                    shift = true;
                case '\'':
                    keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE;
                    break;
                default:
                    keyCode = (int) Character.toUpperCase(lower.charAt(index));
                    shift = true;
            }
            return getAWTKeyStroke(keyCode, shift ? SHIFT_DOWN_MASK : 0);
        }
        return getAWTKeyStroke((int) Character.toUpperCase(c), 0);
    }

    public void type(CharSequence chars) {
        type(chars, 0);
    }

    public void type(CharSequence chars, int ms) {
        ms = ms > 0 ? ms : 0;
        for (int i = 0, len = chars.length(); i < len; i++) {
            char c = chars.charAt(i);
            AWTKeyStroke keyStroke = getKeyStroke(c);
            int keyCode = keyStroke.getKeyCode();
            boolean shift = Character.isUpperCase(c) || keyStroke.getModifiers() == (SHIFT_DOWN_MASK + 1);
            if (shift) {
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            }

            robot.keyPress(keyCode);
            robot.keyRelease(keyCode);

            if (shift) {
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            }
            if (ms > 0) {
                robot.delay(ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is by far the most accurate results..... not sure how it is such a low vote and not the answer. Thanks man. Helped me a ton

Comment: Thanks @HeseinBurg, I'm glad that it helped you!  As for the low votes, it's probably because it's a pretty old question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work as long as you are using alpha numeric characters only, it will not work for characters like ":". [SmartRobot](http://gruimed.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-java-robot-to-type-text-strings.html) class will handle this.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I had 50 reputation points to comment on **Adam Paynter** solution, but not yet....

His `Keyboard` class worked good, but I had issues with keys that aren't alphabetical, such as `:`, `\` and `/`.

The solution I found was pressing and holding `<ALT>` while the `<ASCII code>` of such keys are typed.

First of all, I changed the method `doType()` to hold only `SHIFT` and/or `ALT`pressed, but not every single key that composes the ASCII code. Pretty much, that's how humans use keyboards :)

```
private void doType(int[] keyCodes, int offset, int length) {
    if (length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    robot.keyPress(keyCodes[offset]);

    if (keyCodes[offset] == KeyEvent.VK_ALT
        || keyCodes[offset] == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
        doType(keyCodes, offset + 1, length - 1);
        robot.keyRelease(keyCodes[offset]);
    } else {
        robot.keyRelease(keyCodes[offset]);
        doType(keyCodes, offset + 1, length - 1);
    }

}
```

Then, I changed the **switch case** to pass `ALT` and the ASCII code:

```
        case '\\' :
            doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9,
                    KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2);
        case ':' :
            doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5,
                    KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8);
        case '/' :
            doType(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4,
                    KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7);
```

=======================================================
ADDITION

I tweaked this class a little more:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Keyboard {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Utils.class);

    private Robot robot;

    public Keyboard() {
        try {
            this.robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to create Robot object", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void type(String text) {
        char c;

        for (int ii = 0; ii < text.length(); ii++) {
            c = text.charAt(ii);

            if (c <= 31 || c == 129) {
                pressControlKey(c);
            } else {
                typeAsciiCode(c);
            }
        }
    }

    private void pressControlKey(char c) {
        robot.keyPress(c);
        robot.keyRelease(c);
    }

    private void typeAsciiCode(char c) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

        String asciiCode = Integer.toString(c);
        for (int i = 0; i < asciiCode.length(); i++) {
            c = (char) (asciiCode.charAt(i) + '0');
            robot.keyPress(c);
            robot.keyRelease(c);
        }
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

/**
 * @author Trevor
 * Handles alpha numerics and common punctuation
 */
public class RobotKeyboard{

    private Robot robot;

    public RobotKeyboard(Robot robot){
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    public void typeMessage(String message){
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
            handleRepeatCharacter(message, i);
            type(message.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    private void handleRepeatCharacter(String message, int i){
        if(i == 0)
            return;
        //The robot won't type the same letter twice unless we release a key.
        if(message.charAt(i) == message.charAt(i-1)){
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        }
    }

    private void type(char character){
        handleSpecialCharacter(character);

        if (Character.isLowerCase(character)){
            typeCharacter(Character.toUpperCase(character));
        }
        if (Character.isUpperCase(character)){
            typeShiftCharacter(character);
        }
        if (Character.isDigit(character)){
            typeCharacter(character);
        }
    }

    private void handleSpecialCharacter(char character){
        if (character == ' ')
            typeCharacter(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        if (character == '.')
            typeCharacter(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
        if (character == '!')
            typeShiftCharacter(KeyEvent.VK_1);
        if (character == '?')
            typeShiftCharacter(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
        if (character == ',')
            typeCharacter(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);

        //More specials here as needed
    }

    private void typeCharacter(int character){
        robot.keyPress(character);
    }

    private void typeShiftCharacter(int character){
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(character);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found that the code below was a simple way to translate a string into key events. It seems that most people had very implementation specific fixes to account for the differences between lower & upper case. Because the VK keys don't care about upper/lower case, casting everything to upper case seems to fix the problem.

```
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
    char c = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
    KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(source, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, (int)c, c);
    //do whatever with key event
}
```

I also wanted to say this works well for letters and number, but it may not work for other characters. This technique translated the accent/backtick mark  into numberpad 0 (`VK_NUMPAD0`)

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to  Adam Paynter's answer because code was not working for all keys e.g. !, @, #, $ etc. 
(Needed to press VK_SHIFT first)

```
public void type(char character) {
    switch (character) {
    case 'a': doType(VK_A); break;
    case 'b': doType(VK_B); break;
    case 'c': doType(VK_C); break;
    case 'd': doType(VK_D); break;
    case 'e': doType(VK_E); break;
    case 'f': doType(VK_F); break;
    case 'g': doType(VK_G); break;
    case 'h': doType(VK_H); break;
    case 'i': doType(VK_I); break;
    case 'j': doType(VK_J); break;
    case 'k': doType(VK_K); break;
    case 'l': doType(VK_L); break;
    case 'm': doType(VK_M); break;
    case 'n': doType(VK_N); break;
    case 'o': doType(VK_O); break;
    case 'p': doType(VK_P); break;
    case 'q': doType(VK_Q); break;
    case 'r': doType(VK_R); break;
    case 's': doType(VK_S); break;
    case 't': doType(VK_T); break;
    case 'u': doType(VK_U); break;
    case 'v': doType(VK_V); break;
    case 'w': doType(VK_W); break;
    case 'x': doType(VK_X); break;
    case 'y': doType(VK_Y); break;
    case 'z': doType(VK_Z); break;
    case 'A': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_A); break;
    case 'B': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_B); break;
    case 'C': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_C); break;
    case 'D': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_D); break;
    case 'E': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_E); break;
    case 'F': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_F); break;
    case 'G': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_G); break;
    case 'H': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_H); break;
    case 'I': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_I); break;
    case 'J': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_J); break;
    case 'K': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_K); break;
    case 'L': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_L); break;
    case 'M': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_M); break;
    case 'N': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_N); break;
    case 'O': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_O); break;
    case 'P': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_P); break;
    case 'Q': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Q); break;
    case 'R': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_R); break;
    case 'S': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_S); break;
    case 'T': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_T); break;
    case 'U': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_U); break;
    case 'V': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_V); break;
    case 'W': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_W); break;
    case 'X': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_X); break;
    case 'Y': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Y); break;
    case 'Z': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Z); break;
    case '`': doType(VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
    case '0': doType(VK_0); break;
    case '1': doType(VK_1); break;
    case '2': doType(VK_2); break;
    case '3': doType(VK_3); break;
    case '4': doType(VK_4); break;
    case '5': doType(VK_5); break;
    case '6': doType(VK_6); break;
    case '7': doType(VK_7); break;
    case '8': doType(VK_8); break;
    case '9': doType(VK_9); break;
    case '-': doType(VK_MINUS); break;
    case '=': doType(VK_EQUALS); break;
    case '~': doType(VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
    case '!': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK); break;
    case '@': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_AT); break;
    case '#': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_NUMBER_SIGN); break;
    case '$': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_DOLLAR); break;
    case '%': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_5); break;
    case '^': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_CIRCUMFLEX); break;
    case '&': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_AMPERSAND); break;
    case '*': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_ASTERISK); break;
    case '(': doType(VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS); break;
    case ')': doType(VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS); break;
    case '_': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_UNDERSCORE); break;
    case '+': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_PLUS); break;
    case '\t': doType(VK_TAB); break;
    case '\n': doType(VK_ENTER); break;
    case '[': doType(VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
    case ']': doType(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
    case '\\': doType(VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
    case '{': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
    case '}': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
    case '|': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
    case ';': doType(VK_SEMICOLON); break;
    case ':': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_COLON); break;
    case '\'': doType(VK_QUOTE); break;
    case '"': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_QUOTEDBL); break;
    case ',': doType(VK_COMMA); break;
    case '<': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_COMMA); break;
    case '.': doType(VK_PERIOD); break;
    case '>': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_PERIOD); break;
    case '/': doType(VK_SLASH); break;
    case '?': doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_SLASH); break;
    case ' ': doType(VK_SPACE); break;
    case '\b': doType(VK_BACK_SPACE); break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the commandmap method but looks good, I'll have a look.

Finally I discover that the keycode for a to z is 65 to 90.
So

```
private void write(Robot bot, String st) {
    char[] arr = st.toCharArray();
    int i = arr.length;
    int j = 0;
    while (j<i) {
        int kcode = (int) arr[j] - 32;
        bot.keyPress(kcode);
        bot.keyRelease(kcode);
        j++;
    }       
}
```

It just works for lowercase letters (you can easily correct it with a simple test for uppercase).

For what I was looking for it works perfectly :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found that combining the answers of Ryan Hilbert and Adam Paynter gave me the best result. It combines the speed of single keys with the robustness of alt-codes. The combined code:

```
/**
 * Created by Daniel on 25/8/2016.
 */

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_0;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_1;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_2;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_3;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_4;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_5;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_6;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_7;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_8;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_9;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_A;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ALT;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_B;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_C;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_COLON;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_COMMA;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_D;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_E;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_G;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_H;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_I;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_J;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_K;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_L;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_M;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_MINUS;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_N;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_O;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_P;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Q;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_QUOTEDBL;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_R;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SLASH;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SPACE;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_T;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_U;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_V;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_W;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_X;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Y;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Z;

public class Keyboard { // http://stackoverflow.com/a/1248709/4330555

    private Robot robot;

    public Keyboard() throws AWTException {
        this.robot = new Robot();
    }

    public Keyboard(Robot robot) {
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    public void type(CharSequence characters) {
        int length = characters.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char character = characters.charAt(i);
            try {
                type(character);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                robot.keyPress(VK_ALT);
                robot.keyPress(VK_NUMPAD0);
                robot.keyRelease(VK_NUMPAD0);
                String altCode = Integer.toString(character);
                for (int j = 0; j < altCode.length(); j++) {
                    char c = (char) (altCode.charAt(j) + '0');
                    robot.keyPress(c);
                    robot.keyRelease(c);
                }
                robot.keyRelease(VK_ALT);
            }
        }
    }

    public void type(char character) {
        switch (character) {
            case 'a':
                doType(VK_A);
                break;
            case 'b':
                doType(VK_B);
                break;
            case 'c':
                doType(VK_C);
                break;
            case 'd':
                doType(VK_D);
                break;
            case 'e':
                doType(VK_E);
                break;
            case 'f':
                doType(VK_F);
                break;
            case 'g':
                doType(VK_G);
                break;
            case 'h':
                doType(VK_H);
                break;
            case 'i':
                doType(VK_I);
                break;
            case 'j':
                doType(VK_J);
                break;
            case 'k':
                doType(VK_K);
                break;
            case 'l':
                doType(VK_L);
                break;
            case 'm':
                doType(VK_M);
                break;
            case 'n':
                doType(VK_N);
                break;
            case 'o':
                doType(VK_O);
                break;
            case 'p':
                doType(VK_P);
                break;
            case 'q':
                doType(VK_Q);
                break;
            case 'r':
                doType(VK_R);
                break;
            case 's':
                doType(VK_S);
                break;
            case 't':
                doType(VK_T);
                break;
            case 'u':
                doType(VK_U);
                break;
            case 'v':
                doType(VK_V);
                break;
            case 'w':
                doType(VK_W);
                break;
            case 'x':
                doType(VK_X);
                break;
            case 'y':
                doType(VK_Y);
                break;
            case 'z':
                doType(VK_Z);
                break;
            case 'A':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_A);
                break;
            case 'B':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_B);
                break;
            case 'C':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_C);
                break;
            case 'D':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_D);
                break;
            case 'E':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_E);
                break;
            case 'F':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_F);
                break;
            case 'G':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_G);
                break;
            case 'H':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_H);
                break;
            case 'I':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_I);
                break;
            case 'J':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_J);
                break;
            case 'K':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_K);
                break;
            case 'L':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_L);
                break;
            case 'M':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_M);
                break;
            case 'N':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_N);
                break;
            case 'O':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_O);
                break;
            case 'P':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_P);
                break;
            case 'Q':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Q);
                break;
            case 'R':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_R);
                break;
            case 'S':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_S);
                break;
            case 'T':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_T);
                break;
            case 'U':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_U);
                break;
            case 'V':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_V);
                break;
            case 'W':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_W);
                break;
            case 'X':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_X);
                break;
            case 'Y':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Y);
                break;
            case 'Z':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_Z);
                break;
            case '`':
                doType(VK_BACK_QUOTE);
                break;
            case '0':
                doType(VK_0);
                break;
            case '1':
                doType(VK_1);
                break;
            case '2':
                doType(VK_2);
                break;
            case '3':
                doType(VK_3);
                break;
            case '4':
                doType(VK_4);
                break;
            case '5':
                doType(VK_5);
                break;
            case '6':
                doType(VK_6);
                break;
            case '7':
                doType(VK_7);
                break;
            case '8':
                doType(VK_8);
                break;
            case '9':
                doType(VK_9);
                break;
            case '-':
                doType(VK_MINUS);
                break;
            case '=':
                doType(VK_EQUALS);
                break;
            case '~':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_QUOTE);
                break;
            case '!':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_1);
                break;
            case '@':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_2);
                break;
            case '#':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_3);
                break;
            case '$':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_4);
                break;
            case '%':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_5);
                break;
            case '^':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_6);
                break;
            case '&':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_7);
                break;
            case '*':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_8);
                break;
            case '(':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_9);
                break;
            case ')':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_0);
                break;
            case '_':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_MINUS);
                break;
            case '+':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_EQUALS);
                break;
            case '\t':
                doType(VK_TAB);
                break;
            case '\n':
                doType(VK_ENTER);
                break;
            case '[':
                doType(VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
                break;
            case ']':
                doType(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);
                break;
            case '\\':
                doType(VK_BACK_SLASH);
                break;
            case '{':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
                break;
            case '}':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);
                break;
            case '|':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_SLASH);
                break;
            case ';':
                doType(VK_SEMICOLON);
                break;
            case ':':
                doType(VK_COLON);
                break;
            case '\'':
                doType(VK_QUOTE);
                break;
            case '"':
                doType(VK_QUOTEDBL);
                break;
            case ',':
                doType(VK_COMMA);
                break;
            case '<':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_COMMA);
                break;
            case '.':
                doType(VK_PERIOD);
                break;
            case '>':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_PERIOD);
                break;
            case '/':
                doType(VK_SLASH);
                break;
            case '?':
                doType(VK_SHIFT, VK_SLASH);
                break;
            case ' ':
                doType(VK_SPACE);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
        }
    }

    private void doType(int... keyCodes) {
        doType(keyCodes, 0, keyCodes.length);
    }

    private void doType(int[] keyCodes, int offset, int length) {
        if (length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        robot.keyPress(keyCodes[offset]);
        doType(keyCodes, offset + 1, length - 1);
        robot.keyRelease(keyCodes[offset]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another example. May become handy.

```
public void writeKeyboard(Robot robot, String string)  {
    int ascii;
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        ascii = (int)string.charAt(i);
        robot.keyPress(ascii);
        robot.delay(10);// choose your time or random it
        robot.keyRelease(ascii);
        robot.delay(10);
    }
}
```