# Can a java program "type" into another windows program like notepad

Tags: java, process, types, notepad

is there anyway to type into a notepad.exe process from a JAVA process?

Comment: Please let know why do you want to do that, so that we can answer the question in the light of that knowledge.

Comment: I need to copy some data that I have in a java app into a form that resides into another app (customer name, address, phone number, etc)

Comment: There is no safe way to do this because Java can't control other applications. Yes you might be able to use a Robot, but it is not reliable because you can't guarantee that the Notepad application has focus when you invoke the Robot from Java.

Comment: Why dont you save the data in a text file in one app and read from that very text file from your other app?

Answer (score 18):

Yes, using the robot is the solution:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Notepad {

    static int keyInput[] = { KeyEvent.VK_J, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_V,
            KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_SPACE };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad");

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        for (int i = 0; i < keyInput.length; i++) {
            robot.keyPress(keyInput[i]);
            robot.delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to convert a String to keyEvents check this question 
[Convert String to KeyEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248510/convert-string-to-keyevents)

Comment: Oh, I've got plenty of ideas for uses of this ;)