# Entering Text in Textbox of a jar File using Shell Script

Tags: jar

I have a graphical interface in jar file. There is a text box in there and a button in the window. I manually enter the text into it and then click the button to get the required output.

Now I want to make this thing automatic using a shell script. I wish to pass my input file using redirection. The shell script should open the jar file copy the text in the text box and click the button automatically so that I get the result instantaneously. Could anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a out of the box solution for this, what I can think about is :

Create a simple java class which is the launcher of your GUI java app and to perform operations like typing and button click like

1. Using java Robot class. Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875092/robot-class-java-typing-a-string-issue) or
2. Using a GUI testing utility like [fest](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) to do those user operations automatically

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more or provide me with some more relevant links. I didnt quiet understand.