# Press a key with Java

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible to press a key with Java. Not quite sure how to approach this. There must be some type of class that has like sendKeyPress(); or something.

Comment: In what? Swing? the console? an applet? GWT?

Comment: What I am hoping to achieve is mouse over somewhere and then press a key and it saves the mouses pos. Then it goes back to it and clicks there.

Comment: The `Robot` class from my answer even allows you to move your mouse. And the [`MouseInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html) class is good for remembering the mouse position, too. Good luck!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it easily with the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. That just virtually presses the button, with no special targeting or anything.

For example, to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Here's another question. How would I take a single character like a and convert it to a keycode?

Comment: @Sauce If you mean what I mean, then I've used [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248510/convert-string-to-keyevents).

Comment: But sometimes you can find that roboted key press happens outside your application - in another, unwanted one, if you switch between them.

Comment: @Zon Yes, that's absolutely true and it is a thing one _must_ be aware of. In that case, you probably don't want to press the virtual key programatically, but create a key press event programatically - for example for you Swing app or for whatever reason. Both solutions have their usages.

Answer (score 0):

```
Action act = new Action(driver);
act.sendkeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```