# Script to type out a text file

Tags: java, text-files

I've been wanting to make a program that takes a text file and types it out into a different form. In the current application, I'd have it type out 500 characters, press enter, and continue with the next 500. This could be used with twitter, for example, to type long text files into tweet form. I have no intent to distribute this, so System-specific solutions would be fine. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

What would be the best language to go about doing this? I am already familiarised with Java, but I'm not sure how to get it to use my keyboard directly. Is there a way for Java to do this? If not, what would be a language suitable for my application?

Comment: primarily opinion-based 
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442500/7024081) answer you could use the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) API in Java.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Which you possible could use in combination with reading the text file 500 characters at a time.