# Keybd_event underscore provide wrong output

Tags: c#, keyboard-events, user32

I had create a little program that simulate keyboard event that I used for filled data in Oracle but when I use keybd_event for introduce the character underscore, the output is wrong
If _ is not the last character, when the program simulate the next character add automatically the character -
Example
I need to tape 09_80
For underscore I use combination of VK_RSHIFT with VK_OEM_MINUS
the output is 09_-80

Could someone help me?
I had try also with InputSimulator but it run properly just with Windows 8

Here below some lines of codes from my program, 
Thanks in advance
Best regards

//KEYBOARD ACTIONS

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void keybd_event(int bVk, int bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int MapVirtualKey(int uCode, int uMapType);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern string SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, string wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;


    public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
```

//SEND CHAR

```
    public static void SendChar(char c)
    {
        if (bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            return;
        }  
        if(c=='_')
        {


            keysPress(VK_RSHIFT,VK_OEM_MINUS)
        }

        int vk = VkKeyScan(c);
        int sc = MapVirtualKey(vk, 0);
        PressKeyDn(vk, sc);
        ReleaseKeyUp(vk, sc);


    }

    //SEND STRING
    public static void SendString(string s)
    {

            foreach (char c in s)
            {
                SendChar(c);
            }

    }

    //PRESS KEY DOWN
    public static void PressKeyDn(int VK_Code, int SC_Code)
    {
        keybd_event(VK_Code, SC_Code, 0, 0);
    }

    //RELEASE KEY UP
    public static void ReleaseKeyUp(int VK_Code, int SC_Code)
    {
        keybd_event(VK_Code, SC_Code, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }

    //Press Special Key
    public static void keyPress(int VK_key)
    {
        if (bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            return;
        }  
        int sc = MapVirtualKey(VK_key, 0);
        PressKeyDn(VK_key, sc);
        ReleaseKeyUp(VK_key, sc);

    }

    //Press Special Key Combination 2 keys
    public static void keysPress(int VK_Key1,int VK_Key2)
    {
        if (bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            return;
        }  
        int sc1 = MapVirtualKey(VK_Key1, 0);
        int sc2 = MapVirtualKey(VK_Key2, 0);
        PressKeyDn(VK_Key1, sc1);
        PressKeyDn(VK_Key2, sc2);
        ReleaseKeyUp(VK_Key2, sc2);
        ReleaseKeyUp(VK_Key1, sc1);

    }

    //Press Special Key Combination 3 keys
    public static void keysPress(int VK_Key1, int VK_Key2,int VK_Key3)
    {
        if (bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            return;
        }  
        int sc1 = MapVirtualKey(VK_Key1, 0);
        int sc2 = MapVirtualKey(VK_Key2, 0);
        int sc3 = MapVirtualKey(VK_Key3, 0);
        PressKeyDn(VK_Key1, sc1);
        PressKeyDn(VK_Key2, sc2);
        PressKeyDn(VK_Key3, sc3);
        ReleaseKeyUp(VK_Key3, sc3);
        ReleaseKeyUp(VK_Key2, sc2);
        ReleaseKeyUp(VK_Key1, sc1);
    }
```

Comment: Sigh, the numerous ways that simulating key strokes can fail... VK_RSHIFT is not correct, the left and right shift keys produce the same virtual key.  Only if you need to check which one is down do you use  VK_L/RSHIFT.  You must use VK_SHIFT instead.  Whether that produces the problem, well, maybe.

Comment: Unfortunately I had tried with VK_RSHIFT+VK_OEM_MINUS, WITH VK_LSHIFT+VK_OEM_MINUS, and VK_SHIFT+VK_OEM_MINUS the result is always the same.

If underscore is the last char the result is ok (example if I want tape 0_ the result is 0_).
The problem is when I tape another char after underscore, if I want tape 0_ and after another 0 the result will be 0_-0

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some test I had found where is the problem and I had fixed it.
_ (underscore) means a continuation of a statement on a second line, for this reason the next char taped start with -.
I had fixed this problem excluding the next char from the method in this way.

```
public static void SendChar(char c)
    {
        bool und = false;
        if (c == '_')
        {
            und = true;
        }
        int vk = BMDLCommands.VkKeyScan(c);
        int sc = BMDLCommands.MapVirtualKey(vk, 0);
        if(und)
        {
            keysPress(VK_SHIFT, VK_OEM_MINUS);
            MethodInvoker met = delegate
            {
                keyPress(vk);
            };
        }
        else
        {
            BMDLCommands.PressKeyDn(vk, sc);
            BMDLCommands.ReleaseKeyUp(vk, sc);
        }
    }
```

now the output is totally correct.
Thanks a lot for the help