# write output to command prompt using java

Tags: java, cmd, output

I am trying to open a command prompt from a java class and send output to the new command prompt.
I can open `cmd` using [`process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). Gone through all the answers on SO,but couldn't figure out how can I pass the output to the just created `cmd` window.

Comment: What about starting with some java tutorials?

Comment: Please reformulate. You want to output from a Java application to a distinct Windows CMD ?

Comment: yes sending the output to cmd@rbntd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute cmd commands via Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java)

Comment: @xenteros .. Suppose I would like to display Hello on cmd,how to do that ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the problem is that to display a `cmd` CLI, you have to call `cmd /C start`, where you call `cmd` (actually `conhost`?) and ask it to start another instance with a  CLI. If you try to write to the process' OS, you're actually writing to the first `cmd` process, which has no interface.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be practical or even usable, but it does the job :

```
String[] command = {"cmd", "/c", "start", "cmd.exe"};
try {
    new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
    Robot r = new Robot();

    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
} catch (IOException | AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This opens a CMD and write (a bit too literally maybe) "Hello" in the CMD.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248709/6882070) if you want to type a String.

Comment: God, this is awful... Here pour soul, take my upvote for having had to consider this possibility ! (On a more serious tone, if no better solution is found one should obviously create a function to translate a `String` to a list of keystrokes)

Comment: @Aaron It has fortunately already been done ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248510/convert-string-to-keyevents