# Using Robot and Keyboard Class to Type Text in Search Bar on Google

Tags: java, bots

I have been messing around with the Robot class recently, and wanted to try to remotely type a search in the search bar, but I can't seem to get the entire string to type out. **Only the last letter ends up being typed in the search bar. The rest of the text ends up being printed in the terminal** where I run the code.

I start by moving the mouse above the selection box.

I click the mouse twice (once to make safari the active window and once to activate the bar)

Then I let the type function type for me. It uses the keypress and keyrelease methods.

Does anybody know how to make the entire string type in the search bar?

Also I give credit to Sensei_Shoh on his stackoverflow post at [Convert String to KeyEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248510/convert-string-to-keyevents)
for his code from lines 38 to the end.
Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*; 
import static java.awt.AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke;
import static java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK;

public class myBot
{
    public static Robot robot;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        robot = new Robot();

        //Move to search bar
        robot.delay(500);
        robot.mouseMove(600,140);

        //Activate search bar
        robot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
        robot.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
        robot.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
        robot.delay(1000);

        //Type in search bar;
        //YOUR STRING  \/
        String input = "ipad pro";
        for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
        {
            type(input.substring(i, i+1));
        }
    }
    private static AWTKeyStroke getKeyStroke(char c) {
        String upper = "`~'\"!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?";
        String lower = "`~'\"1234567890-=[]\\;,./";

        int index = upper.indexOf(c);
        if (index != -1) {
            int keyCode;
            boolean shift = false;
            switch (c) {
                case '~':
                    shift = true;
                case '`':
                    keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE;
                    break;
                case '\"':
                    shift = true;
                case '\'':
                    keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE;
                    break;
                default:
                    keyCode = (int) Character.toUpperCase(lower.charAt(index));
                    shift = true;
            }
            return getAWTKeyStroke(keyCode, shift ? SHIFT_DOWN_MASK : 0);
        }
        return getAWTKeyStroke((int) Character.toUpperCase(c), 0);
    }

    public static void type(CharSequence chars) {
        type(chars, 0);
    }

    public static void type(CharSequence chars, int ms) {
        ms = ms > 0 ? ms : 0;
        for (int i = 0, len = chars.length(); i < len; i++) {
            char c = chars.charAt(i);
            AWTKeyStroke keyStroke = getKeyStroke(c);
            int keyCode = keyStroke.getKeyCode();
            boolean shift = Character.isUpperCase(c) || keyStroke.getModifiers() == (SHIFT_DOWN_MASK + 1);
            if (shift) {
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            }

            robot.keyPress(keyCode);
            robot.keyRelease(keyCode);

            if (shift) {
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            }
            if (ms > 0) {
                robot.delay(ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider setting [`Robot#setAutoDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#setAutoDelay-int-) to help insert a delay between the key pressed and key released events

Comment: I tried using robot.delay(100) between all the computations already, but that had no effect besides slowing the program down.

Comment: No, you didn't, not the way I suggested.  `Robot` can, automatically, place a delay between EVERY event it triggers (that includes `mousePress` and `mouseRelease` and `keyPress` and `keyRelease`), not just between a batch of events as you are doing

Comment: Ok. I typed robot.setAutoDelay(1000) right after I initialize robot at the beginning of main. I got a different result, but still not the full result. I got the same "o" but this time, there was a space before it. Btw I really appreciate your help. :)