# How to Ignore Case on Key Input in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to check if the user typed the y key, but I want it to be lowercase. I don't know how to check that. I am using `if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_Y)`, but I need the y key to be lowercase, when it is capital it is messing up my code.

Comment: Would this link help? I cant comment yet, so i m posting it here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1248510/16034206.

Answer (score 2):

`getKeyCode` returns the code of the key pressed, regardless of the intent or modifiers.  To see if the shift modifier is applied, try using `getModifiers()` on the event.

Note that these key events are low-level, so making sense of the events in a more natural way is going to be more complex.

Comment: This will not work with `Caps Lock` is on

Comment: Caps Lock doesn't show up in the modifiers?  If not, then this feels like it is too low-level for things like capitals - unless the developer really wants to keep track of every modifier key's state (yuck).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like

```
KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()).equalsIgnoreCase("y")
```

This converts the keycode to a string then compares it case insensitive.

Or if you only want to accept lowercase just `equals` e.g.

```
KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()).equals("y")
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `getKeyCode()` happens to return the ASCII code, and the value of constant `VK_Y` is a integer 89 ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Y)). This value corresponds to char `Y` from ASCII table.

If you want a lowercase, use the corresponded value to y instead of constant `KeyEvent.VK_Y`. According the ASCII table, a integer 121 corresponds to char `y`.

So, you can do like:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == 121)
```

or:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
if (e.getKeyCode() == 'y') {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Please add more context to the answer