# Get unicode value of character

Tags: java, keycode

Is there any way to get the keycode of a char? For example

```
getKeycode('C');
```

Is there anything like that?

Thanks

Comment: the "keycode" *is* the `char`, eg `char c = 'A';` and `char c = 65;` are identical statements

Comment: What are these "keycodes" that you speak of?

Comment: This has been asked before, without a 'clean' answer, but you'll find some options in these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664896/get-the-vk-int-from-an-arbitrary-char-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248510/convert-string-to-keyevents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char ch='c';
int code = ch;
System.out.println(code);
```

OUTPUT:

```
99
```

just for escape char `\` you have to use like char `ch='\\';`

Comment: @JonMannerberg It should work with every character, but be carefull with the special ones. `\` should be `\\`(because it is the escaping character and with its help, you can see the keycode of other characters.

Comment: just for escape char \ you have to use like char ch='\\';

Answer (score 5):

```
public static int KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar( int key );
```

This will return an extended key code for the unicode character **key**.

As stated at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getExtendedKeyCodeForChar%28int%29):

> Returns: for a unicode character with a corresponding VK_ constant -- this VK_ constant; for a character appearing on the primary level of a known keyboard layout -- a unique integer. If a character does not appear on the primary level of a known keyboard, VK_UNDEFINED is returned.

Answer (score 4):

A way is this:

`char c = 'f';`

`System.out.println("code="+(int)c);`

I mean, you should make a casting form `char` to `int`;

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println((int) 'c');