# Recreate typed text from keycodes

Tags: java, parsing, keycode

I a Java program I have the list of typed keyCodes and need to compute the text that was typed in.

For example:

16-72-69-76-76-79-16-49 means "Hello!".

I could do this manually of course,
but is there some functionality in Java or a library to aid with this?
Preferably also with specifying the keyboard layout...

Comment: Check out similar questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504615/java-get-keycode-of-a-char and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833709/converting-int-to-char-in-java should help

Answer (score 0):

From what I know there is not standard and as you hinted, it depends on keyboard layout.  I trust you've checked out this Java lib:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

But as far as a library that helps universal from OS/device/layout I don't know if one exists.