# How to determine keycode in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Get keycode of a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504615/java-get-keycode-of-a-char)

I have a String which can contain alphabet, digits, +, -, = etc. I want to get the key code of each character so that I can use that in `KeyEventData()` argument. I am able to detect only alphanumeric characters.

How do I detect a keypress such as +, :, }, etc. which requires a shift key press?

Comment: Are you getting this string through actual keypress events? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The "extended" key presses are combinations of a basic virtual key and shift state. So "+" would be `VK_EQUALS` + `SHIT_DOWN_MASK`

Comment: No. It is a predefined string. I want to simulate a key press event based on its value so that I can enter that value in JXTreeTable cell.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : so I need to determine for each character whether its an extended key press or not.

Comment: @DarkKnight unfortunately yes :P - I did a massively long switch statement that would, given a char, return a a key sequence (essentially a list of key strokes) required to replicate the char. Every Google search I did basically come back to the same conclusion. If you have better luck, I'd love to know!

Answer (score 1):

In the KeyEvent you receive as parameter in a KeyListener -I am assuming you are using this listener-, you have the methods `getKeyCode()` and `getKeyChar()`.

Comment: No. I am not accepting string from keyboard. It is predefined in the program.

Comment: @gersonZaragocin Also, `getKeyChar` isn't guaranteed to return a result (I believe `keyTyped` does, can't remember if it's `keyPressed` or `keyReleased` that returns an empty char).  `KeyCode` is only useful if you have the extended state (shift, alt, ctrl) of the keystroke (in this context)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`AWTKeyStroke.getKeyStroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTKeyStroke.html#getAWTKeyStroke%28char%29):

```
assert KeyEvent.VK_A == AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke("pressed A").getKeyCode();
  && KeyEvent.VK_COLON
    == AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke("pressed COLON").getKeyCode();
  && KeyEvent.VK_BRACERIGHT
    == AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke("pressed BRACERIGHT").getKeyCode();
```